# use different fragments for steps

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, stepper

Im using [android-material-stepper](https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper) library for step implementation but here i can use one fragment and it is showing 3 steps.

i need different fragments for different steps, how to use like that?

i have different views like Fragment 1 is having calendar, Fragment 2 is having buttons, fragment 3 is having input boxes. i want to use all 3 fragments for each 3 steps respectively.

i implemented as shown in that GitHub page and there they are using only 1 fragment for 3 steps. is there any way to use 3 fragments? if not how can i differentiate 3 functions for each steps in same fragment?

please help!

Comment: please post some relevant codes here, none is likely to download that library to help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement this behaviour in the **StepperAdapters** *createStep()* function.

You could do it like this:

```
@Override
public Step createStep(int position) {

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY, position);

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            MyCalendarStepFragment calendarFragment = new MyCalendarStepFragment();
            calendarFragment.setArguments(b);
            return  calendarFragment;
        case 1:
            MyButtonStepFragment buttonFragment = new MyButtonStepFragment();
            buttonFragment.setArguments(b);
            return  buttonFragment;
        case 2:
            MyInputStepFragment inputFragment = new MyInputStepFragment();
            inputFragment.setArguments(b);
            return  inputFragment;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put any value in "CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY"
I tried the same process but my first step is empty
here is my adapter

```
private val pages = SparseArray<Step>()

override fun createStep(@IntRange(from = 0)position: Int): Step {
    //val step = StepFragmentSample()
    //val b = Bundle()
    //b.putInt(CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY, position)
    //step.setArguments(b)
    //return step
    val b = Bundle()
    val CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY = "CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY"
    b.putInt(CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY, position)
    return when (position) {
        2 -> {
            //FormAddBashDocumentFragment()
            val addBashDocumentFragment = FormAddBashDocumentFragment()
            addBashDocumentFragment.setArguments(b)
            return addBashDocumentFragment

        }
        1 -> {
            //FormAddClaimsFragment()
            val addClaimsFragment = FormAddClaimsFragment()
            addClaimsFragment.setArguments(b)
            return addClaimsFragment
        }
        0 -> {
            //FormAddClaimBatchesFragment()
            val addClaimBatchesFragment = FormAddClaimBatchesFragment()
            addClaimBatchesFragment.setArguments(b)
            return addClaimBatchesFragment
        }

        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported position: " + position)

    }
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 3
}

override fun findStep(position: Int): Step? {
    return if (pages.size() > 0) pages.get(position) else null
}

override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): View {
    var step: Step? = pages.get(position)
    if (step == null) {
        step = createStep(position)
        pages.put(position, step)
    }

    val stepView = step as View
    container.addView(stepView)

    return stepView
}

override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
    container.removeView(`object` as View)
}

override fun getViewModel(@IntRange(from = 0)position: Int): StepViewModel {
    //Override this method to set Step title for the Tabs, not necessary for other stepper types
    val builder = StepViewModel.Builder(context)
        .setTitle("New batch")
    when (position) {
        0 -> builder
            .setTitle("Batch")
            .setEndButtonLabel("claim")
            .setBackButtonLabel("Cancel")
            .setBackButtonStartDrawableResId(StepViewModel.NULL_DRAWABLE)
        1 -> builder
            .setTitle("claim")
            .setBackButtonLabel("Back to batch")
        2 -> builder
            .setTitle("Documents")
            .setBackButtonLabel("Back to claim")
            .setEndButtonLabel("I'm done!")
        else -> throw java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported position: $position")
    }
    return builder.create()
}
```